# Unable to show popmenu on RecyclerView item click

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have menu option in Recyclerview item row when user clicks on that row element then I want to show pop menu. I have implemented this functionality and on click message is showing on log but popmenu is not showing up.

Below is my code:

```
public class PdfAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PdfAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<Pdfs> pdfList;

public PdfAdapter(Context context, List<Pdfs> pdfList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.pdfList = pdfList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pdf_item_row,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Pdfs model = pdfList.get(position);

    holder.pdfName.setText(model.getFilenamename());
    holder.datTime.setText(model.getDatetime());

    holder.menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("clik","Hello");

            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context,holder.menu);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.row_menu);

            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.itemShare:

                            break;
                        case R.id.itemDel:

                            break;
                        case R.id.itemDownload:
                            Toast.makeText(context,model.getFileurl(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return pdfList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView pdfName,menu,datTime;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        pdfName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pdfName);
        menu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu);
        datTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.datTime);
      }
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call `.show()` method on `popupMenu`.

Add below line at last inside click listener.

```
popupMenu.show();
```

Comment: Oh my bad, made a silly mistake Thanks it worked now.